# How can I add photo and details to vCard using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vcf-vcard

I want to add an image and more details to the contact vcard using JS. it's like a business page when people see the page they can save my contact through id="save-btn", And I want to add more than Name, phone, email.

The code working fine, but I don't know how to add photo and other details to the vcard, Like company, job, location, and more.

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");

saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Get the contact information from the website
  var contact = {
    name: "John Smith",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    email: "john@example.com"
  };
  
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], {
    type: "text/vcard"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
  newLink.textContent = contact.name;
  newLink.href = url;

  newLink.click();
});
```

Save the vcard from html page through save-btn.

`<button id="save-btn">Save Contact</button>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for How to Ask and what makes a minimal reproducible example. It would be very helpful if you could edit the question so your code would show the effort and things you have tried out. Right now this question needs more details and clarity before it can be answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the format of VCF files:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

You can set `PHOTO` property as image, see Properties section to know all the available properties that you can set in a VCF file.

Example of photo property:

```
version: value
2.1: PHOTO;JPEG:http://example.com/photo.jpg
2.1: PHOTO;JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:[base64-data]
3.0: PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;VALUE=URI:http://example.com/photo.jpg
3.0: PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=b:[base64-data]
4.0: PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/jpeg:http://example.com/photo.jpg
4.0: PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:[base64-data]
```